# frame more than 1 equation (but not all) of an align environment

Tags: align, boxes

I think the question is self-explanatory. I have an align environment with four equations and I want only the last two of them framed in a single box. So not separately framed.

If I try to achieve this by creating two align environments and boxing the entire second align environment then the equation groups are centered aligned and I dont want that. I want to preserve the alignment of the original group. Namely on the equal sign.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a =& b\\
c =& d\\
    \framebox{e =& FFF\\
f =& GGG}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not like that no, it hides the `&` from `align`. BTW: When you use `=&` write it as `={}&` otherwise the spacing after `=` will be wrong. In this case you could just as well use `&=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option, using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library from TikZ; `\tikzmark` allows the placement of marks to be used to draw the frame (which can be as fancy as desired):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw
  ([shift={(-1em,2.5ex)}]pic cs:starta) 
  rectangle 
  ([shift={(1em,-1.25ex)}]pic cs:enda);
\draw[red!60!black,thick,rounded corners,fill=yellow!30]
  ([shift={(-1em,2.5ex)}]pic cs:startb) 
  rectangle 
  ([shift={(1em,-1.25ex)}]pic cs:endb);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
c &= d\\
\tikzmark{starta}e &= FFF\\
f &= GGG\tikzmark{enda}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
cc &= d\\
\tikzmark{startb}eee &= FFF\\
f &= GGG\tikzmark{endb}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Since internal calculations are involved, the code needs two runs to stabilize.

In the same spirit, but with shorter code, you can use the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\fcol}{white}
\renewcommand{\bcol}{black}
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
c &= d\\
\tikzmarkin{a}(1em,-1.5ex)(-1em,2.5ex)e &= FFF\\
f &= GGG\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{align*}

\renewcommand{\fcol}{yellow!30}
\renewcommand{\bcol}{red!60!black}
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
cc &= d\\
\tikzmarkin{b}(1em,-1.5ex)(-1em,2.5ex)eee &= FFF\\
f &= GGG\tikzmarkend{b}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 just it gives me another motivation to really start learning `TikZ`! I have been planning this for so long and I am each time amazed at by its power. Only these internal calculations are a bit scary off course, even though I somehow grasp the sense of them. Thx again

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem You're welcome! I've updated my answer with another option using this time the `hf-tikz` package (this gives shorter code).

Comment: as a last question @GonzaloMedina. This should also work to highlight certain elements of a matrix then ?

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem Sure! The idea is the same: place marks at some strategic locations and then draw the frame using those marks.

Comment: OK but what I really want actually is transform the rectangle into a `node` and at a reference name to this `node` so that I can later use it to draw arrows between the boxes. Let me reformulate: suppose that in the above example we had boxed both the first two and the last two (of the four), how then could I have drawn an arrow between the two ? I was thinking adding a named node to both of them but I just can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly neither the most optimal solution nor the most general, but it works (in this peculiar case): using a combination of the `\Aboxed` command of the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package (which loads and complements `amsmath`) and two `aligned` environments.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\begin{aligned}
    a &= b\\
    c &= d
  \end{aligned}\\
  \Aboxed{&{\begin{aligned}
    e &= FFF\\
    f &= GGG
  \end{aligned}}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the braces surrounding the second `aligned` environment: as explained in `mathtools` [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf):

> As `\Aboxed` looks for the alignment & it may be necessary to hide
>   constructions like matrices that also make use of &. Just add a set of
>   braces around the construction you want to hide.

Comment: Note that the overall alignment only seems to fit here because a, c, e, f have a similar width. Counter measures might be needed if the widths are not the same (such as using `\mathmakebox` to make a right aligned boxed with a certain given width

Comment: You're right, I've just noticed that. Waiting for a more general solution then, if it exists…

Comment: if you look closely, you will see that the equals signs are *not* aligned between the boxed and not-boxed groups.  unfortunately, i don't know the answer -- but it's a good question.

Comment: @barbara beeton Indeed, same problem as noticed by daleif. In that case it is probably the bigger width of the f letter.

Comment: a "counter measure" that might work is to figure out what is the widest left-hand-side element, and force one other left-hand-side element (in the boxed or not-boxed portion(s)) to that same width.  not elegant, but the easiest workaround i can think of.

Comment: thx for all your insights. I am really not such an expert. But I was amazed that it was for instance not a functionality available in the `empheq` package. I am not quite sure whether I completely understand the suggestion using `mathmakebox`

Comment: see my above comment about the TikZ solution. I like yours also but the TikZ one is really very very flexible. So sorry for not accepting yours @fpast

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem No problem! It's perfectly true, the tikz solution is by far the best one. :-)